# HTML unit cannot find form for some reason. I suspect because of the angularJS but not sure

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, htmlunit

I am using HTMLunit to login to a page then upload a file. So far I have been able to login but I am not able to locate the form. It gives me an error that it cant find the element but it exists in the HTML page.

JAVA CODE.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
   // webClient.getOptions().set(true);

    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
    try {
        HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient
                .getPage("https://controlcenter-itv2.centurylink.com/business/controlcenter/home");  //loggin into this page
        HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("lqLogin");        //grabbing the form on the page
        ((HtmlInput) form.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id='userId']")).setValueAttribute("*****");      //setting up the username for the field
        HtmlInput passWordInput = form.getInputByName("password");   
        passWordInput.removeAttribute("disabled");
        passWordInput.setValueAttribute("****");  // password for the field

       HtmlPage page1 = form.getInputByValue("Login").click(); // works fine
       HtmlPage page2= (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://controlcenter-itv2.centurylink.com/business/controlcenter/ordering/initiate-orders-whsl/batch");
        System.out.println(page2.asText());


        HtmlForm form1 = page2.getFormByName("orderForm"); //doesnt work
                        //page2.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id='batchUpload']");  

       // page1 = form1.getInputByValue("Browse").click(); 




      //*[@id="fileName"]



        HtmlFileInput input = (HtmlFileInput)form1.getFirstByXPath("//*[@id='fileName']");  //trying to get the form on the upload page not working

       // input.setContentType("text/html");

           //file that needs to be uploaded
        //input.setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");

        input.setValueAttribute("file:/C:\fileuploadTEST.txt");
```

This is the HTML code

```
<form id="batchOrderForm" class="ng-pristine ng-valid" name="orderForm">
```

This is the error i am getting

```
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ElementNotFoundException: elementName=[form] attributeName=[name] attributeValue=[orderForm]
    at com.gargoyles[enter image description here][1]oftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.getFormByName(HtmlPage.java:644)
```

Comment: Do you have a nested form on the page? I had a similar problem before and was banging my head against a wall untill I found out...

Comment: Ist a tag has in `id` you should go by the id-attribute not the name-attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The form is not on the page when I load it with javascript disabled, therefore I assume it is added later by javascript.

So your problem might be that you have to wait for the form to appear.

In general search for the problem this way:

If e.g. a form is not found, I simply log the page source before I try to access an element.

In your case:

```
 HtmlPage page2= (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://controlcenter-itv2.centurylink.com/business/controlcenter/ordering/initiate-orders-whsl/batch");
        System.out.println(page2.asXml());


        HtmlForm form1 =(HtmlForm) page2.getElementById("batchOrderForm");
```

Than I have a look at the log output if the desired element is can be found in the output. Often I need to wait for some javascrit to finish changing the page source.